# asp.net mvc webforms like gridview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

is there a grid for asp.net mvc that acts just like the asp.net webforms datagrid 
the behavior that I need is to pass to the grid a DataTable without specifying the amount of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should not be using any of the server controls in MVC.

You will need to use a table and iterate through thr required objects, MVC allows much more control over the HTML which meens that you have to do a little more work.

I think you best look at the NerdDinner example.

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

And here is an example,

```
 <table>

      <% foreach (var category in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(category.data) %></td>            
        <tr>

      <% } %>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com). They provide a Grid HTML helper, which is very powerful.

I have extended that Grid in my free library, [etcetera.Mvc](http://etceteramvc.codeplex.com), added AJAX paging, sorting  and some more nice options.

Comment: with the mvcContrib grid you have to specify to the grid each column, i have a dynamic datasource (it's a matrix like in reporting services), so i need something like in asp.net webforms, cuz i don't how many columns i'm going to have

Comment: The mvccontrib grid also supports auto columns. See the enclosed samples.